# $|y-x|^{-7} = C^*$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this differential equation -
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y(y-8x)}{x(x-8y)}$$
and to get the answer for
$$|y-x|^{-7} = C^*?$$
I used the stuff we learned- that $$\frac{dy}{dx} = F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) = F(v)$$
and got here: $$\frac{1-8v}{v\cdot(9v-9)}\cdot \frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{1}{x}$$
$$\frac{-1}{9}\cdot\int(\frac{1}{v}+\frac{7}{v-1})\,dv = \int\frac{dx}{x}$$
$$\frac{-1}{9}\cdot(\ln(v)+7\cdot(\ln(v-1)))=\ln(x)+c$$
and after integration I'm stuck here- $$e^{\frac{-1}{9}}\cdot(v-1)^{7}\cdot v = x+c$$
and now I don't know how to continue.
and I don't understand what $y(x)$ is supposed to be.
What do I do from here?

Comment: Please add the partial-fraction decomposition between the last two formulas. You have some grave errors in the exponentiation after the integration.

Comment: @LutzLehmann edited

Comment: Yes, that is correct, and the integration too, but you mixed up the exponentiation rules.

Comment: @LutzLehmann what is the correct form? And how to I move from there to the $|y-x|^{-7}$ ?

Comment: $(v-1)=(y-x)/x$. In short, coefficients become exponents, sums become products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the correct application of the exponentiation rules, you should get from the logarithm equation to
$$
\ln|v|+7\ln|v-1|=-9\ln|x|+\tilde c\\
v(v-1)^7=Cx^{-9}\\
y(y-x)^7=Cx^{-1}
$$

Comment: so $(y-x)^{-7}=Cx\cdot(y)$ ?

Comment: Yes, that appears to be the case. $C=0$ and $C=\infty$ are special cases that should have been addressed earlier (in some way) in the computation to avoid division-by-zero.